# An alternative to the Ubuntu Software Center for elementary OS?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, package-manager

I recently installed elementary OS and many people are saying that the Ubuntu Software Center isn't good for eOS, and I have to agree.

I have heard of [AppGrid](http://www.appgrid.org/), but am not sure. I am also aware of Synaptic but I'm looking for a more "app store"-like program, rather than just a package manager.

Are their any other alternatives? (You can recommend AppGrid)

Answer (score 2):

The only one specific to eOS is their own 'AppCenter' which is still in development, but you can give it a try by adding their PPA:

```
https://launchpad.net/appcenter
```

To try it out run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appcenter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install appcenter
```

It is still in development, so expect bugs.

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly try that out. If I prefer it I'll accept your answer

Comment: Hmm, cannot install (I have the x32 Intel Pentium 4 3.4GHz, if it's helpful): `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies. appcenter : Depends: libappstore0 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative for USC under elementary OS 0.3 Freya is the Lubuntu Software Center, which is lightweight and uses GTK+. You can install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center
```